# Use a function inside an event both located inside an object and than invoke that

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello I am new at this object oriented javascript (or any oop for that matter) and I am trying out some things, and keep getting stuck at a point.

In this simple example I am trying to use a function within an event so I can reuse both of those events/functions whenever needed. A click event should trigger a specific function, and I use parameters for both the element that can be clicked and the function that needs to be invoked when being clicked upon.

My code thus far:
Simple title that could be clicked upon:

```
<h2 class="click_title">Show alert on click</h2>
```

js:

```
var myScripts = {
    alertText : function() {
        alert("it works")
    },
    onClicks : function( element, fn ) {
        $( element ).on( "click", function( fn ){
            fn();
        });
    }
}

myScripts.onClicks(".click_title", myScripts.alertText);
```

I am using jQuery in this case to select the actual element, though I am sure this is of no matter in this issue.

The weird thing is that when I use the following line:

```
myScripts.onClicks(".click_title", myScripts.alertText());
```

It shows the alert on load rather than on click.

Hope this is a little bit clear, and more than that I hope it makes sense somehow in what I am trying to achieve.
The only thing I can think of right now is that maybe it isn't possible to add events into an object to reuse, but again I can be wrong.
Please shed me some light.

Any help much appreciated.

Update: I noticed that the following however does work:

```
var myScripts = {
    alertText : function() {
        alert("it works")
    },
    clicky : function( element, fn){$( element ).click(fn)}

}

myScripts.clicky( ".click_title", myScripts.alertText);
```

So what makes this line:

```
function( element, fn){$( element ).click(fn)}
```

different from this line:

```
function( element, fn ) {
        $( element ).on( "click", function( fn ){
                fn();
            });
        }
```

???

Comment: `fn` here: `function( fn ){...}` is Event object, not that `fn` you've passed to `onClicks`.

Comment: Not 100% sure about what you mean with this, please explain if possible. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering your first snippet only.

Your issue is in `onClicks`.

```
onClicks : function( element, fn ) { // fn is the passed event handler
    $( element ).on( "click", function( fn ){ // fn is Event object
        fn(); // fn is Event object, not the passed handler function
    });
}
```

Event handlers are invoked by event queue, which calls the handler with a single argument – Event object. Hence `fn` passed to the handler function defined in `.on`'s arguments refers to the Event object, which is specific to this event.

Fixing this is easy:

```
onClicks : function( element, fn ) {
    $( element ).on( "click", function( e ){
        fn( e );
    });
}
```

`e` is the automatically passed Event object, `fn` is read from the outer scope, hence it keeps its original value you've passed when attaching the event to the element. Notice also, that `e` is passed to the actual handler too, just in case you'd need it there.

[A live demo at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aq3z9u51/1/). The fiddle also shows you, how you can pass the Event object to handler and use it there.

Comment: Thank you @Teemu, this does seem to work as intended. I do seem to keep struggling however with passing additional parameters to the function that is added inside the event handler, in case they are needed, replacing e.g.: alert with .css("fontSize",parameterValue). Will keep testing a bit and if needed post another question. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @asturnick You can pass parameters for example like at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aq3z9u51/2/). I've used an object, but you can use any data type you need.

Comment: Absolutely beautiful, so you just created an object on the fly. Amazing, thanks again.

Comment: @asturnick You're wellcome. Actually the example is quite simple, the argument is hardcoded to the file. Just as an example, you can also use real [dynamic arguments](http://jsfiddle.net/aq3z9u51/3/) in JavaScript.

Answer (score -1):

You're looking at the wrong difference between those 2 code snippets!

The issue is with this line:

```
myScripts.onClicks(".click_title", myScripts.alertText());
```

Note that the second parameter is the result of *calling* `alertText` - not a reference to the `alertText` function. Try this instead, and your first example should work:

```
myScripts.onClicks(".click_title", myScripts.alertText);
```

(The only difference is the removal of the brackets after `alertText`; passing the function, instead of calling it and passing its result.)

Comment: This explains why the second snippet alerts on load, but falls back to the OP's first snippet, which as they say, doesn't work either.